# Other navigation-menu content in each section of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to code navigation for my website. I have a one_page website with 4 sections. When I open hamburger on my first section the menu appears. In the menu I have menu-links and thumbnail (preview) of the section. Now I would like to code it so when I am  in the other section of the page and I click the hamburger menu it opens with a preview of the section where I clicked hamburger. I am JS newbie and do not really know how to do it. Maybe someone can give me a hint? Beest regards

```js
const hamburger_menu = document.querySelector(".hamburger-menu");
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

hamburger_menu.addEventListener("click", () => {
  container.classList.toggle("active");
});

const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item');

menuItems.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // hamburger.classList.remove('active');
    container.classList.remove('active');
  })
})
```

```html
<section class="navigation">
  <div class="container" id="main">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="">
          <h3 class="logo">Lorem<span>Lorem</span></h3>
        </a>
        <div class="hamburger-menu">
          <div class="bar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main-container">
      <div class="main">
        <header>
          <div class="overlay">
            <div class="inner">
              <div class="image"><img src="assets/img/logo.svg" alt="" /></div>
              <div class="text">
                <h1>Lorem Lorem</h1>
                <br />
                <h3>Lorem Lorem</h3>
                <br />
                <div class="icon-box">
                  <a href="#" target="_blank">
                    <div class="icon">
                      <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#" target="_blank">
                    <div class="icon">
                      <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#" target="_blank">
                    <div class="icon">
                      <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="contact-box">
                  <i class="fas fa-phone"> <span>phone</span></i>
                  <p>mail</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        </div>

        <div class="shadow one"></div>
        <div class="shadow two"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="links">
        <ul>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#" style="--i: 0.05s;">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#about" style="--i: 0.1s;">Menu 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#two" style="--i: 0.15s;">Menu 2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#three" style="--i: 0.2s;">Menu 3</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#main" style="--i: 0.25s;">Menu 4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="about-us" id="about">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Neque recusandae at voluptatibus suscipit hic iusto debitis consequatur quas nulla sint esse, quibusdam eos voluptates earum nemo laboriosam, quae optio modi?</p>
</section>


.about-us {
  z-index: -10;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation .container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #EFD9D5;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #EFCAC3 50%, #B3D3C1 100%);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.navigation .image {
  margin: 40px;
}

.navigation .image img {
  width: 340px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navigation .image img {
    width: 260px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .navigation .image img {
    width: 180px;
  }
}

.navigation .text {
  margin: 40px;
}

.navigation .text h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #3A3B3D;
}

.navigation .text h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .navigation .text h1 {
    font-size: calc(20px + 18 * ((100vw - 320px) / 850));
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .navigation .text h1 {
    font-size: 38px;
  }
}

.navigation .text h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #3A3B3D;
}

.navigation .text h3 {
  font-size: 15px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .navigation .text h3 {
    font-size: calc(15px + 15 * ((100vw - 320px) / 850));
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .navigation .text h3 {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}

.navigation .text .icon-box {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

.navigation .text .icon-box .icon {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #3A3B3D;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin: 10px;
}

.navigation .text .icon-box .icon:hover {
  background: #DAE8DF;
  border: none;
}

.navigation .text .icon-box .icon i {
  color: #A06665;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.navigation .text .icon-box .icon i {
  font-size: 18px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .navigation .text .icon-box .icon i {
    font-size: calc(18px + 12 * ((100vw - 320px) / 850));
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .navigation .text .icon-box .icon i {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}

.navigation .text .contact-box {
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.navigation .text .contact-box i {
  color: #9d6261;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.navigation .text .contact-box i {
  font-size: 12px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .navigation .text .contact-box i {
    font-size: calc(12px + 8 * ((100vw - 320px) / 850));
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .navigation .text .contact-box i {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}

.navigation .text .contact-box i span {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: "Roboto",
 sans-serif;
}

.navigation .text .contact-box p {
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: #9d6261;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.navigation .text .contact-box p {
  font-size: 12px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .navigation .text .contact-box p {
    font-size: calc(12px + 8 * ((100vw - 320px) / 850));
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .navigation .text .contact-box p {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}

.navigation a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation .navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3rem;
  z-index: 300;
}

.navigation .menu {
  max-width: 72rem;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  color: #3A3B3D;
}

.navigation .logo {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  line-height: 4rem;
  color: #A06665;
}

.navigation .logo span {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #3A3B3D;
}

.navigation .hamburger-menu {
  height: 4rem;
  width: 3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
      -ms-flex-pack: end;
          justify-content: flex-end;
}

.navigation .bar {
  width: 1.9rem;
  height: 1.5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #3A3B3D;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
  position: relative;
}

.navigation .bar:before,
.navigation .bar:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: #3A3B3D;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.navigation .bar:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-9px);
          transform: translateY(-9px);
}

.navigation .bar:after {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(9px);
          transform: translateY(9px);
}

.navigation .main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left;
          transform-origin: left;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.navigation header {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: url("/assets/img/bg7.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.navigation .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(239, 217, 213, 0.3);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.navigation .inner {
  max-width: 35rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #3A3B3D;
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

.navigation .title {
  font-size: 2.7rem;
}

.navigation .btn {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  padding: 0.6rem 1.8rem;
  background-color: #DAE8DF;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: #3A3B3D;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation .container.active .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
          transform: rotate(360deg);
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navigation .container.active .bar:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0) rotate(45deg);
          transform: translateY(0) rotate(45deg);
}

.navigation .container.active .bar:after {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
          transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
}

.navigation .container.active .main {
  -webkit-animation: main-animation 0.5s ease;
          animation: main-animation 0.5s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(16deg) translateZ(310px) scale(0.6);
          transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(16deg) translateZ(310px) scale(0.6);
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navigation .container.active .main {
    display: none;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes main-animation {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
            transform: translate(0);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(16deg) translateZ(310px) scale(0.6);
            transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(16deg) translateZ(310px) scale(0.6);
  }
}

@keyframes main-animation {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
            transform: translate(0);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(16deg) translateZ(310px) scale(0.6);
            transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(16deg) translateZ(310px) scale(0.6);
  }
}

.navigation .links {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 2;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navigation .links {
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
  }
}

.navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.navigation .links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3A3B3D;
  padding: 0.7rem 0;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
          transform: translateY(10px);
  -webkit-animation: hide 0.5s forwards ease;
          animation: hide 0.5s forwards ease;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s;
  transition: -webkit-transform .2s;
  transition: transform .2s;
  transition: transform .2s, -webkit-transform .2s;
}

.navigation .links a:hover {
  color: white;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
          transform: scale(1.2);
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navigation .links a {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
}

.navigation .container.active .links a {
  -webkit-animation: appear 0.5s forwards ease var(--i);
          animation: appear 0.5s forwards ease var(--i);
}

@-webkit-keyframes appear {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
            transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
            transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes appear {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
            transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
            transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes hide {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
            transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
            transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}

@keyframes hide {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
            transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
            transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}

.navigation .shadow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left;
          transform-origin: left;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-color: #3A3B3D;
}

.navigation .shadow.one {
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.15;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navigation .shadow.one {
    display: none;
  }
}

.navigation .shadow.two {
  z-index: -2;
  opacity: 0.1;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navigation .shadow.two {
    display: none;
  }
}

.navigation .container.active .shadow.one {
  -webkit-animation: shadow-one 0.6s ease-out;
          animation: shadow-one 0.6s ease-out;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(16deg) translateZ(215px) scale(0.6);
          transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(16deg) translateZ(215px) scale(0.6);
}

@-webkit-keyframes shadow-one {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
            transform: translate(0);
  }
  5% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(16deg) translateZ(310px) scale(0.6);
            transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(16deg) translateZ(310px) scale(0.6);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(16deg) translateZ(215px) scale(0.6);
            transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(16deg) translateZ(215px) scale(0.6);
  }
}

@keyframes shadow-one {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
            transform: translate(0);
  }
  5% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(16deg) translateZ(310px) scale(0.6);
            transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(16deg) translateZ(310px) scale(0.6);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(16deg) translateZ(215px) scale(0.6);
            transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(16deg) translateZ(215px) scale(0.6);
  }
}

.navigation .container.active .shadow.two {
  -webkit-animation: shadow-two 0.6s ease-out;
          animation: shadow-two 0.6s ease-out;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(16deg) translateZ(120px) scale(0.6);
          transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(16deg) translateZ(120px) scale(0.6);
}

@-webkit-keyframes shadow-two {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
            transform: translate(0);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(16deg) translateZ(310px) scale(0.6);
            transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(16deg) translateZ(310px) scale(0.6);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(16deg) translateZ(120px) scale(0.6);
            transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(16deg) translateZ(120px) scale(0.6);
  }
}

@keyframes shadow-two {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
            transform: translate(0);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(16deg) translateZ(310px) scale(0.6);
            transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(16deg) translateZ(310px) scale(0.6);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(16deg) translateZ(120px) scale(0.6);
            transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(16deg) translateZ(120px) scale(0.6);
  }
}

.navigation .container.active .main:hover + .shadow.one {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(16deg) translateZ(230px) scale(0.6);
          transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(16deg) translateZ(230px) scale(0.6);
}

.navigation .container.active .main:hover {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(16deg) translateZ(340px) scale(0.6);
          transform: perspective(1600px) rotateY(16deg) translateZ(340px) scale(0.6);
}
```

Comment: Add the CSS to your code so we can see what's happening.

Comment: SASS doesnt work in the browser by default, can you provide the CSS compiled version instead?

Comment: Thanks for info. I edited my post